# C# How to use one method for two classes with Generic type?

Tags: c#, class, generics, printing

I need to merge two different print method into one. I have two generic classes and my own generic list class.
Let's say I have

```
static void Print(string fv, MyListClass<Module> A,
            string top)
 and static void Print2(string fv, MyListClass<Student> A,
            string top)
```

Inside of the method is the same, but how to make them to be one method and in Main class I choose in parameters which one class list am I printing, Module either Student. My data is in:

```
MyListClass<Student> Stud; 
MyListClass<Module> Mod;
```

Comment: `Print<T>(string fv, T A, string top)` ?

Comment: In this case it can not find my MyListClass methods

Comment: OK, then how about `Print<T>(string fv, MyListClass<T> A, string top)` ?

Comment: If `Module` and `Student` don´t share any members, why should they have any common method that handles them at all? Having said this generics are for - well - everything that **is** common. If that is not the case here, don´t use generics.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, I already thought of it from your first example, thanks.

Comment: @HimBromBeere They have some fields in common

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have two <strike>generic</strike> classes and my own generic list class.

Why do you have your own list class? You generally shouldn't. Assuming it implements `IEnumerable<T>`:

Let both `Module` and `Student` implement a common interface with the properties you want to print, say `IPrintable`:

```
public interface IPrintable
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
}

public class Module : IPrintable { ... }
public class Student : IPrintable { ... }
```

Now create a method with a generic parameter:

```
void Print<T>(string fv, IEnumerable<T> A, string top)
    where T : IPrintable
{
    foreach (var item in A)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name + ": " + item.Description);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you simply create a base class, derive both Module and Student class from it, and then use the base class in the signature of the single method.